# Is it possible to convert HashMap in java to List using MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

We are trying to find a way to convert HashMap to List using mapstruct but there is  no such help on the internet. Does anyone know a way to do it using mapstruct?

We have tried defining abstract class and use Abstract mapping but nothing works

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN,
implementationPackage = "com.mapstruct.mapper.impl")
public abstract class OrderLineMapper {
  public com.internal.epfo.v1.OrderLine toOrderLineList(Map.Entry<Integer, OrderLine> orderLineEntry) {
    com.internal.epfo.v1.OrderLine orderLine = new com.internal.epfo.v1.OrderLine();
    orderLine.setCategoryTypeCode(orderLineEntry.getValue().getCategoryTypeCode());
    orderLine.getProducts().addAll(getProductInfoList(orderLineEntry.getValue().getProducts()));
    return orderLine;
  }

  List<com.internal.epfo.v1.ProductInfo> getProductInfoList(EnrichProductInfoMap<String, ProductInfo> products) {
    List<com.internal.epfo.v1.ProductInfo> productInfo = products.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList<com.internal.epfo.v1.ProductInfo>::new ));
    return productInfo;
  }

  @MapMapping
  public abstract List<com.internal.epfo.v1.OrderLine> toOrderLineList(
      Map<Integer, OrderLine> orderLine);
}
```

Can’t generate mapping method from non-iterable type to iterable type.

Comment: Unrelated: consider **importing** your types, instead of having such incredible line noise by using fully qualified types all over the place. That alone makes your code 10 times harder to read than necessary.

Comment: this maybe a duplicated question.
please see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451671/how-mapping-to-list-with-mapstruct

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box support for converting `Map` into `List`. However, you can add a custom method.

```
public abstract class OrderLineMapper {
  public OrderLineV1 toOrderLine(Map.Entry<Integer, OrderLine> orderLineEntry) {
    OrderLineV1 orderLine = new OrderLineV1();
    orderLine.setCategoryTypeCode(orderLineEntry.getValue().getCategoryTypeCode());
    orderLine.getProducts().addAll(getProductInfoList(orderLineEntry.getValue().getProducts()));
    return orderLine;
  }

  List<ProductInfoV1> getProductInfoList(EnrichProductInfoMap<String, ProductInfo> products) {
    List<ProductInfoV1> productInfo = products.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList<ProductInfoV1>::new ));
    return productInfo;
  }

  public List<OrderLineV1> toOrderLineList(Map<Integer, OrderLine> orderLine) {
    return orderLine == null ? null : toOrderLineList(orderLine.entrySet());
  }

  public abstract List<OrderLineV1> toOrderLineList(Collection<Map.Entry<Integer, OrderLine> orderLineCollection);
}
```