# Is it possible to convert from HashMap to List using MapStruct

Tags: java, list, dictionary, mapping, mapstruct

I know there is a similar question (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805919/is-it-possible-to-convert-hashmap-in-java-to-list-using-mapstruct)), but I've found no useful answer there. Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class QuestionType {
    private String type;
}

class Profile {
    private String name;
    private int id;
}

class ProfileResponse {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private String type;
}
```

How could I convert a `HashMap<QuestionType, Profile>` to `List<ProfileResponse>` using MapStruct (1.3.1)

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ProfileResponseMapper {
    List<ProfileResponse> toProfileResponse(Map<QuestionType, Profile> profiles);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MapStruct doesn't have an implicit conversion mechanism for mapping `Map` into `List`. However, you can do a trick to understand `Map` as a collection of `Entry` and map each entry into the list item:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ProfileResponseMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "type", source = "key.type")
    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "value.name")
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "value.id")
    ProfileResponse map(Map.Entry<QuestionType, Profile> profile);
        
    default List<ProfileResponse> toProfileResponse(Map<QuestionType, Profile> map) {
        return map.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .map(this::map)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

```
ProfileResponseMapper mapper = ...    // ProfileResponseMapper.INSTANCE or @Autowired 
Map<QuestionType, Profile> map = ...  // input Map

List<ProfileResponse> profileResponseList = mapper.toProfileResponse(map);
```

The code uses the advantage of Java 8 `default` methods and Stream API, otherwise use an `abstract class` and a for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to follow the KISS principle:
Iterate via a bi-consumer through the map, create your ProfileResponse Objects and put them to a list.

```
map.forEach (key, val -> 
    {
        ProfileRespone respone = new ProfileResponse(key.type, val.name, val.id);
        list.add(response);
    }
```